# gcc profiling while debugging

Tags: gcc, gdb, gprof

Is it possible to get profiling information during debugging (gdb). E.g. to get profiling information (something similiar to gprof results) between two breakpoints?
I tried to use gdb and manipulate with gmon.out while debugging, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Very likely not. And why would you want to? This sounds like an XY-problem. What do you actually want to measure or debug?

Comment: I know that function Func on the Nth call produces wrong results. So I want to get trace of called functions from Func on the Nth call. The easiest way seems to me use results of gprof, as there is a graph